# How can I use a string instead of a char in list comprehension

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeerror

right now I'm trying to make a function that can see if the input `item` is already in `list`, here's my code.

```
list :: [String]
list = ["a","b"]

listCheck :: String -> [String]
listCheck item = [(x:xs)| (x:xs) <- list, x == item]
```

the current problem is that it can only filter if the input is a character and not a string, when I left the type undeclared Haskell made the function `Char -> [String]`, and it worked perfectily fine, it returned an empty list when it wasn't included and it returned a list with the item in it if it was included. When I added the `String -> [String]` it returned this error.

```
Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'
      Expected: Char
      Actual: String
```

I tried to change it to `x <- item` and it compiled but it just gave `[item, item]` every time. I want to know what I can do to make it work with strings instead of chars, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This part makes x as char.

```
(x:xs) <- list
```

each element mapping like

```
["a","b"]

'a':[] => x = 'a', xs = []
'b':[] => x = 'b', xs = []
```

so, if you want to check element in list and get found one, how about below.

```
listCheck :: String -> [String]
listCheck item = [x| x <- list, x == item]
```

```
Prelude> listCheck "a"
["a"]
Prelude> listCheck "b"
["b"]
Prelude> listCheck "c"
[]
Prelude>
```

Comment: This can also be written `listCheck = filter . (==)`, which feels to me like it quickly and intuitively conveys the meaning (though a careful reading to verify the intuitive reading may take a few seconds).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think it is good way too, simple and change list ad hook. Question's code might want to include list in function, also be written `listCheck = flip filter list . (==)`.